# How can i increase the size of the window buttons on Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu

The minimize, maximize and close window buttons are too small. They're difficult for me to hit at quickly. I'd like they was similar to Windows', just for reasons of usability.

I'm using Xubuntu 16.4 and i haven't made any change on the default theme/appearance settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those buttons are changed by changing to a different window manager theme. In XFCE's Settings, under Window Manager & the first Style tab:

[image]

Just click on a different theme and see the change immediately. The package `xfwm4-themes` has more themes.

---

Editing a specific theme could in theory change their size, unless they're static images, but it's probably much easier to just pick a different theme with bigger buttons. Looking at `xfwm4-themes` installed files, it *might* be one of the .xpm files, similar to `/usr/share/themes/Wallis/xfwm4/top-right-active.xpm`.

A little experimentation reveals that some themes have only images, some have only .xpm files ("text images"), and some have both. There's several files for each "state" for example the close button has "closed-active", "closed-inactive", and -prelight, -pressed.

- Copying a button's set from one theme's xfwm4 directory to another's seems to copy that button only.

.xpm files may be able to be directly edited, the first few lines are similar to:

```
/* XPM */
static char * maximize_active_xpm[] = {
"18 29 2 1",
```

where the 18 appears to have something to do with the width, and 29 height, but maybe in an "offset" somehow. `gimp` might be able to edit them...